# Draw line from axis to declared function curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code, which displays a normal distribution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussian}{2}
{%
    \pgfmathparse{(1/(#1 * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp((-1 / 2) * (((x - #2)/#1) ^ 2))}%
}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mean}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\std}{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [ 
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=center,
                ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
                xmin=-3, xmax=3
            ]
            \addplot [color=black, mark=none, samples=50] {
                gaussian(\std, \mean)}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I want to do is create a command that takes a standard deviation, mean, and x-value as input, and draws a line from the x-axis to the curve, resulting in a plot like this:

[image: goal]

Ideally, I want to do this without having to duplicate the math in the pgfmathdeclarefunction section, so if there was some way for me to evaluate that function given the standard deviation, mean, and x-value, that would definitely help. It seems like pgfplots is already doing this in plotting the function, so this should be simple in principle, but oddly enough I haven't managed to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually rather straightforward, especially if one slightly adjusts the definition of the Gaussian. I made it a function of three (instead of two) argument, `x`, the standard deviation or width, and the mean. All you need to do to get the vertical line is to say

```
\addplot[<style>] coordinates {(<x>,0) (<x>,{gaussian(<x>,<width>, <mean>)})};
```

which of case can be made a macro.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{declare function={gaussian(\x,\y,\z)=(1/(\y * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp((-1
/ 2) * (((x - \z)/\y) ^ 2));}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mean}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\std}{1}
\newcommand{\VerticalLine}[2][]{
\addplot[#1] coordinates {(#2,0) (#2,{gaussian(#2,\std, \mean)})};}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [ 
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=center,
                ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
                xmin=-3, xmax=3
            ]
            \addplot [color=black, mark=none, samples=50] {
                gaussian(x,\std, \mean)}; 
            \VerticalLine[dashed]{-1}   
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you can simply remove the "\x" parameter from the gaussian function definition (and all the corresponding calls to it), as it is never actually used. Was there any particular reason you decided to include that?

Comment: @rish987 Of course it is used. Just try `\VerticalLine[dashed]{0.5}`. The Gaussian is a function of `x` (the mean and width).

Comment: I removed the "\x" parameter (note that this is distinct from the "x" parameter with no slash in front, which is used in the function) to no ill effect. The call `\VerticalLine[dashed]{0.5}` still drew a line that ended at the curve.

Comment: @rish987 `\x` is just a placeholder. You could name it `\CuteFurryRodent` or whatever.

Comment: Correspondingly, I changed the command to `\addplot[#1] coordinates {(#2,0) (#2,{gaussian(\std, \mean)})};` It seems like, in the second pair of coordinates, the x-position is used as an implicit 'x' parameter to the gaussian function.

Comment: Rather than rename the variable, I removed it entirely from the function definition, and the function behaved identically.

Comment: @rish987 You are of course free to do as you want. However, I would like to argue that the Gaussian is a function of two variables, `x` and some variable controlling its width, and the mean is just a shift that can be implemented by replacing `x` by `x-<mean>`.